# Passing the EXPOSE argument in Dockerfile as user input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

Passing the argument in Dockerfile as user input while building the docker image.

Created a sample Dockerfile that would build a image.

```
### sample dockerfile
    COPY . .
    EXPOSE 7017

# ENV VAR'S
    ENV ELASTIC_APM_CONFIG_FILE=elastic-apm-node.js
    ENV ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME=abc
    ENV ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URLS=http://abc:1234
```

Specifying the EXPOSE Argument in Dockerfile as user input.

Comment: Hi Vicky, could you edit your question and clarify the following: What you are trying to achieve? What you have already tried, and any errors you received? For reference, check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Docker build uses arguments (defined with ARG). Environment variables (defined with ENV) are used by running containers and are not available at build time.

Change your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM ....

ARG EXPOSE_PORT=<some default value>

EXPOSE $EXPOSE_PORT
```

and then pass the value you need in your docker build command:

```
docker build --build-arg EXPOSE_PORT=7017 ....
```